# Unable to find javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery after Spring-Boot 3 Upgrade

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I upgraded Spring Boot Starter Parent from 2.7 to 3.0.2.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
</parent>
```

The code uses some Stored Procedure annotations on entity objects, and they are no longer found:

```
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureParameter;
...

@Entity
@Table(name = "some_table")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "updateproctime", procedureName = "SP1", parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "p_form_name"),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "p_office_code"),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = String.class, name = "p_form_type"),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Date.class, name = "p_processing_date"),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Date.class, name = "p_effctve_dt")
            })})
public class SomeEntity implements Serializable {
   //...
}
```

Any tips?

[image]

Comment: Spring team provides a migration guide for Spring Boot 3.0 at: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: Thanks rph. I found this statement there: `As well as dependency coordinate changes, Jakarta EE now uses jakarta packages rather than javax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot 3 release turned to work with **Jakarta Persistence API** rather than with `javax.persistence.api`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api

Add that dependency and change `import javax.persistence.*;` to `import jakarta.persistence.*;`

Comment: One more question. Not all the javax.persistence.* imports are flagged. Some are fine: import javax.persistence.Column, Id, Entity, SequenceGenerator. Do I change all of them to Jakarta, even though these are OK? As the screenshot shows, not everything is flagged.

Comment: yes, it is recommended